# how to add grand total row in bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have got the results in the following format

```
customer ;  Sales

A        ;  1000

B        ;  1500

c        ; 2500
```

I want to add a grand total row in the results like

```
customer    ;  Sales

A           ;  1000

B           ;   1500

c           ;  2500

Grand Total ;  5000
```

how can I do this?

I have tried roll up function

```
Select customer, sales from `xyz`
group by customer
```

expecting grand total in the output

Answer (score 2):

To add a new row to the query you had, you can use the WITH statement, and use a query like the following:

```
WITH grand_total AS (SELECT SUM(sales) as grand_total FROM TABLE_NAME)
SELECT customer, sales FROM TABLE_NAME
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT 'grand_total' as customer, grand_total.grand_total from grand_total;
```

which will output the following:

```
Row customer      sales 
1    B             1500
2    C             2500
3    A             1000
4    grand_total   5000
```

You can read more information about the [WITH statement](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#with-clause) in the public documentation.